# long list of numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to write a long list of numbers in python, but I don't want to enter the numbers one by one because that's boring. So, how can I do that? For the ones who are familiar with MATLAB, I want to write something witch looks 1:100, but I don't know how to write it in python!
By the way, I can append numbers for a one-element-list in a loop but I am looking for something mostly like a built in operator.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like the builtin `range` function?

```
>>> range(1,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10,2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

in python 3.x, `range` doesn't return a list anymore, it returns a `range object`.  Range objects behave like lists in a lot of ways, but they aren't actually lists.  If you really need a list on python 3.x, you can use `list(range(...))`

Numpy has a similar function `arange` which will work with floats as well:

```
>>> np.arange(1,2,.1)
array([ 1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9])
```

Comment: You might also want to add that `range` returns a list in Python 2 and a generator in Python 3.

Comment: @MRAB -- Careful calling it a generator.  range objects are like generators, but subtly different.  In a lot of ways they're cooler, but you can't do `next(range(10))` and have it work out like you could if `range` returned an actual generator object.