# How to make a list of numbers

Tags: python, list

How do I make a list of numbers from 1-100 without having to type in every single number in python?

```
def number ():
    x = [1,2,3,4...
```

and so on will take forever to write, and I'm guessing there's an easier way that I haven't found.

Comment: Look into [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [long list of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537543/long-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is almost free:

```
x = list(range(1, 101))  # python 3
x = range(1, 101)        # python 2
```

depending on how you use it, it may be better to omit the `list` part (or for python 2: use `xrange`). e.g if you iterate once through every member of the range in a `for` loop.

Comment: List comprehension is better than constructor call no? `[i for i in range(1,101)]`

Comment: @Busturdust, for Python 3, yes.

Comment: 1) readability, 2) I had once upon done some timing tests which suggested list comprehension was quite faster in most cases, but I dont have the documentation available :/ - Also, list comprehension is so great, why not use it whenever you can!

Comment: `$ python3 -m timeit 'list(range(1000))'` -> `10000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 usec per loop` vs. `python3 -m timeit '[i for i in range(1000)]'` -> `10000 loops, best of 3: 45.6 usec per loop`  (Python 3.4.3) - ok, that's just quick and dirty but please elaborate.

Comment: @Busturdust readability? `list(range(1, 101))` looks better to my taste. but i can understand one might prefer the list comprehension.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist check out the link sent ... I think the complexity with only 1000 numbers may not quite show the difference. the more values you use, I would image the list comprehension with slow down slower than the constructor.

Comment: @Busturdust just ran the test for `10**7` and `10**8` (> 1GB in memory). same result. thats as big as i care for a list...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist well Ive certainaly been wrong before! :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic way of doing:

```
l = []
for i in range(1,101):
    l.append(i)
print l
```

or try `list comprehension`

```
x = [i for i range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def numbers():
    return [number for number in range(1,101)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in range(1, 100):
print(f)
```

I think this is easiest

Answer (score -1):

#code for number 1-100
list(range(1,100))

Comment: Format your code and add a little explanation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024453/2227743